# Custom mapping the child array of objects and adding validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

A JSON string is received from the server and I am trying to custom map using the KO Mapping plugin, so that I can add validation using KO validation plugin.

There is a model object named `Player` which has a property named `Trophies` which is an array of objects.

```
// Business Objects
var myPlayer = function (player) {
this.ID = ko.observable(player.ID);
this.Name = ko.observable(player.Name).extend({required: true});
this.Rank = ko.observable(player.Rank);
this.Trophies = ko.observableArray(player.Trophies);
}

var myTrophy = function (trophy) {
this.Name = ko.observable(trophy.Name).extend({required: true});
this.Year = ko.observable(trophy.Year).extend({required: true});
}
```

I don't know how to call the myTrophy so that I can Custom Map the Trophies array along with validation.

```
//KO binding
var playerModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonString, mapping);
ko.applyBindings(playerModel);

// Mapping
var mapping = {
    'Player': {
        create: function (options) {
            var _player = new myPlayer(options.data);
            return _player;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saamisolutions/2TXA5/4/)

if you notice in jsfiddle, if I remove the `Name` property I get the validation message 'This is Required' similarly I would like to get validation message for Trophy Name and Year. Let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to achieve this.

One approach is to use the [arrayMap utility function](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) to call your function for each entry in `player.Trophies`

```
 this.Trophies = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(player.Trophies, myTrophy));
```

Then change `myTrophy` to return an object

```
var myTrophy = function (trophy) {
  return { 
           Name:  ko.observable(trophy.Name).extend({required: true}),
           Year: ko.observable(trophy.Year).extend({required: true})
         }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need your `myPlayer function` (and `myTrophy`) here, because you will do what the plugin already does except for the validation.

You could do this:

```
// Mapping
var mapping = {
    'Name': {
        create: function (options) {
            return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: true });
        }
    },
    'Year': {
        create: function (options) {
            return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: true });
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin will match all properties `Name` and `Year` to add the validation to them.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/2TXA5/6/)

Comment: Thanks. As you said this is matching all properties with those names and I find arraymap utility function mentioned below useful.